# output of my Jinja in Airflow is value but I rather want string how can I get it?

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

code

```
"{{ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='Match_Updated_dates', key='QueryTimeStamp')}}"
```

The Output of the above in my where clause is

Output I am getting:

```
where last_updated_utc > {}
where last_updated_utc > 2021-08-26 11:40:33
```

Desired output

```
where last_updated_utc > '2021-08-26 11:40:33'
```

I want to use it as a String , how can I convert jinja output to String from the value I am getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you need is just to add a single quotation mark you can just do that by adding it.

```
""" SELECT col FROM my_table WHERE date_col='{{ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='Match_Updated_dates', key='QueryTimeStamp')}}' """
```

I'm not sure though why you want to compare dates as strings. I would guess that your end goal is to convert the value into timestamp known to your SQL flavor? My point here is that this is something that you can handle within the SQL itself - for example:

```
""" SELECT col FROM my_table WHERE date_col= CAST ('{{ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='Match_Updated_dates', key='QueryTimeStamp')}}' AS TIMESTAMP)"""
```

A working DAG example:

```
from datetime import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.providers.postgres.operators.postgres import PostgresOperator


def func(task_instance, **context):
    task_instance.xcom_push(key='QueryTimeStamp', value='2021-08-26 11:40:33')


dag = DAG(
    dag_id='my_dag',
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=datetime(2021, 8, 28),
    catchup=False,
)

op1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='Match_Updated_dates',
    python_callable=func,
    dag=dag,
)

op2 = PostgresOperator(
    task_id='sql',
    sql=""" SELECT col FROM my_table WHERE date_col='{{ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='Match_Updated_dates', key='QueryTimeStamp')}}' """,
    postgres_conn_id="postgres_default",
    dag=dag,

)

op1 >> op2
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks I figured out a diff way for this but this is also good to know , I am using as .format in the end of the sql query. I passed the x.com into the .format Did something like this and it worked  ----------->         where last_updated_utc > '{}';
            
        END;
            """.format(country,country,str("{{ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='Match_Updated_dates', key='QueryTimeStamp')}}")) ,  So if you notice I passed it like this '{}' , gave it string form from outside the jinja.

Comment: When you are using f-string you need to replace any two braces of jinja with four.
(`{{` to `{{{{` ) because f-string replace two braces with one while rendering.  Your question however didn't show you are using f-strings.

Comment: I see, Thanks for the info, I had a quick question on PostgresOperator , wanted to know how we can use if statement in PostgresOperator if I want to shoot different queries based on my if condition: like if country = usa then shoot this part of the query and if country = finland then shoot this part of the query in postgres operator.

Comment: You have two options - first solve it on Airflow level with a branch operator that will execute diffrent sql based on your If statement. second option is to place the if statement with in the SQL itself using Jinja engine: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#if however this is not relevant to this question. If you have further problems please open a new question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68973053/how-to-pass-paremeter-in-my-sql-file-in-postgresoperator-airflow

Comment: can you please answer the link I provided