# How to pass paremeter in my .sql file in PostGresOperator airflow?

Tags: python, airflow, postgres-operator

I have sql file and I want to pass parameters to that sql file using PostGresOperator.

```
"""select * from table_{} where id > ID """.format(mytable,myID)
```

My postGresOperator

```
mport_redshift_table = PostgresOperator(
            task_id='copy_data_from_redshift_{}'.format(country),
            postgres_conn_id='postgres_default',
            sql="""
                   select * from table_{} where id > {}
                """.format(mytable,myID)
```

How can I do the same and pass my parameters in my .sql file and still use .format(mytable,myID) ?

so that I can pass them into my referenced .sql file.

Comment: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-postgres/stable/operators/postgres_operator_howto_guide.html#passing-parameters-into-postgresoperator

Comment: How can I do it by my thing? where I am using .format file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the [How-to Guide](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-postgres/stable/operators/postgres_operator_howto_guide.html#passing-parameters-into-postgresoperator) for `PostgresOperator`, you can place your SQL in a file within a subfolder in the dag directory:

```
-- dags/sql/birth_date.sql
SELECT * FROM pet WHERE birth_date BETWEEN SYMMETRIC {{ params.begin_date }} AND {{ params.end_date }};
```

Use `params` to pass in the key/value pairs that would be rendered within the SQL in your file:

```py
get_birth_date = PostgresOperator(
    task_id="get_birth_date",
    postgres_conn_id="postgres_default",
    sql="sql/birth_date.sql",
    params={"begin_date": "2020-01-01", "end_date": "2020-12-31"},
)
```

#### Edit

If you want to do it inline, without using the file, just use any string interpolation mechanism:

```py
sql="""select * from table_{} where id > {} """.format(mytable,myID)
```

or

```py
sql=f"""select * from table_{table_name} where id > {myID} """
```

or if you want to use jinja, taking advantage of any of the [default vairables](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/macros-ref.html#macros-reference), such as a param provided when the DAG was triggered you could do it like this:

```py
sql=f"""select * from table_{{ params.param1 }} where id > {myID} """
```

Comment: Thanks , I read the document , is that the only way to pass the paramenters ? can't I use something like .format instead in my file and pass the parameters, just wondering.

Comment: Yes you can also do it that way. You don't need to create and additional file, even if it's considered as a best practice. You could use `format` or [f-String](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/). I'll edit my answer with an example

Comment: yeah please I would love to know that as well! looking forward to the edit

Comment: @Nicole, No I actually meant using file only, but I understand that without using params parameter I cannot do the file so if I have to do .sql , The .format one i was wondering if we can use it in .sql file but seems like we cannot use the .format inside the .sql file we need to use params parameter.

Comment: @AdityaVerma oh I see! now I get it! Thanks for the feedback. Absolutely, going with `params` parameter and using a .sql file is the preferred way.

Comment: I am using xcom in my Parameter ---                                                     params={"country": country, "dates": "{{ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='Match_Updated_dates', key='QueryTimeStamp')}}"} , But this does not seem to fit well in {{params.dates}}